# TCP sockets dying on LTE

Tags: linux-networking, wireshark, linux-kernel

I have about 25 audio streaming clients built on an i.mx6 arm platform, running linux version  4.3.0-rc2-00019-gbcee19f-dirty #36 SMP Tue Feb 9 15:27:51 EST 2016 armv7l

I find on two specific units on 4g lte (mbr1516) in alberta that the socket is dying about every couple of minutes, while other windows based streaming clients on the network keep working across the same time period.

I really suspect that the 4g cell firewall is messing with these packets, but can't put a finger on it, and not sure where to drill down.

There is in and outbound traffic the whole period spanning 18:11:35 to 18:12:06 to other outside IP's.  I think the the server is a linode setup, its rather unlikely that its a server side issue.

Network configuration is 
Streaming_Box->4G_LTE_Router->internet->Icecast_Server

Addition 1:
This client streaming device can send multiple streams, so If I send two side by side streams, one open http, the other through openvpn, the http gets broken, the tunneled http does not.

[image: Client Capture]
[image: Server Capture]
Code for socket handling

```
void * StreamingThread1(void * ptr) {
    int a, b, SendCount;
    ssize_t BytesSent;
    int Burst = 1;
    time_t timer, timercomp, OnDelay;
    time(&timer);
    time(&OnDelay);
    unsigned char * RxBuff = malloc(5000);
    unsigned char * OutBuff = malloc(65535);
    if (RxBuff == NULL || OutBuff == NULL) {
        MyLog("StreamThread1 Unable to allocate RxBuff or OutBuff\n");
        StartupError(50);
    }
    Control.StreamConnected1 = 0;
    Control.StreamConnectErr = StrmErr_None;
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    int sockfd = -1;
    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct timeval tv;
    int BuffSize = 65535;
    socklen_t optlen = 4;
    tv.tv_sec = 10;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    while (1) {
        usleep(10000); //Give threads a breather
        if (Control.RestartStream1) {
            time(&timer);
            Control.RestartStream1 = 0;
            if (sockfd > -1) {
                close(sockfd);
                sockfd = -1;
            }
            sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
            if (sockfd == -1) {
                Debug("Unable to create socket %s\n", strerror(errno));
                goto ExitConnect;
            }
            setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &tv, sizeof (struct timeval));
            setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *) &tv, sizeof (struct timeval));
            setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &BuffSize, optlen);
            Burst = 1;
            server = gethostbyname((char*) StreamParams.URL1);
            if (server == NULL) {
                Debug("Error finding host %s\n", StreamParams.URL1);
                Control.StreamConnectErr = StrmErr_NoHost;
            } else {
                bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
                serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
                bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
                serv_addr.sin_port = htons(StreamParams.Port1);
                Control.StreamConnected1 = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) != -1;
                if (!Control.StreamConnected1) {
                    Debug("ERROR, unable to connect to %s : %i : %i\n", StreamParams.URL1, StreamParams.Port1, errno);
                    Control.StreamConnectErr = StrmErr_NoConnect;
                    goto ExitConnect;
                } else {
                    Debug("Connected to %s : %i\n", StreamParams.URL1, StreamParams.Port1);
                }
                unsigned char* Message = BuildLogin(0);
                Control.StreamConnected1 = sendto(sockfd, Message, strlen(Message), MSG_NOSIGNAL, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) > -1;
                if (!Control.StreamConnected1) {
                    Debug("ERROR, unable to write message to %s : %i\n", StreamParams.URL1, StreamParams.Port1);
                    free(Message);
                    Control.StreamConnectErr = StrmErr_NoWrite;
                    goto ExitConnect;
                } else {
                    Debug("Login information sent to %s : %i\n", StreamParams.URL1, StreamParams.Port1);
                    free(Message);
                }
                a = recv_catch_eintr(sockfd, RxBuff, 5000, MSG_NOSIGNAL, 10000);
                if (a <= 0) {
                    Control.StreamConnected1 = 0;
                    Debug("Unable to authenticate, nothing received %s\n", strerror(errno));
                } else {
                    if (strstr((const unsigned char*) RxBuff, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK") != NULL) {
                        Debug("Authentication successfull\n");
                        Control.AuthError1 = 0;
                    } else {
                        Control.StreamConnected1 = 0;
                        Control.AuthError1 = 1;
                        Control.StreamConnectErr = StrmErr_Auth;
                        Debug("Authentication Error\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
ExitConnect:
        if (Control.StreamConnected1 && sockfd > -1) {
            if (Burst) {
                b = LameParams.BitRate * 3 * 1000 / 8;
                if (b > AudioBuffSize - 1024) {
                    b = AudioBuffSize - 1024;
                }
                unsigned short Diff = AudioHeadPtr - AudioTailPtr1;
                if (Diff > b) {
                    Burst = 0;
                    for (a = 0; a < b; a++) {
                        OutBuff[a] = AudioBuffer[AudioTailPtr1++];
                    }
                    Control.StreamConnected1 = send(sockfd, OutBuff, b, 0) == b;
                    Debug("Sent %i Burst\n", b);
                }
            } else {
                SendCount = 0;
                while (AudioTailPtr1 != AudioHeadPtr && a < sizeof (AudioBuffer) - 1024) {
                    OutBuff[SendCount++] = AudioBuffer[AudioTailPtr1++];
                }
                if (SendCount > 0 && sockfd > -1) {
                    BytesSent = send(sockfd, OutBuff, SendCount, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
                    Control.StreamConnected1 = (BytesSent > 0);
                    Control.StreamConnectErr = StrmErr_None;
                    if (BytesSent != SendCount) {
                        Debug("Tried %i sent %i\n", SendCount, BytesSent);
                        AudioTailPtr1 -= (SendCount - BytesSent);
                    }
                    if (BytesSent < 0) {
                        AudioTailPtr1 -= SendCount;
                        Debug("Lost Connection errno %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        Control.StreamConnectErr = StrmErr_LostConn;
                        Control.StreamConnected1 = 0;
                        close(sockfd);
                        sockfd = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            //Wait 5 then try again.
            if (sockfd > -1) {
                Debug("Closing socket %i\n", sockfd);
                close(sockfd);
                sockfd = -1;
            }
            time(&timercomp);
            if (timercomp - timer >= 5) {
                Control.RestartStream1 = 1;
                Debug("Stream restart at %i\n", timercomp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question would be more well placed on stackoverflow. As for me it's not a firewall issue, as it work, and then retransmit occur. For me it's a app failure. Might I ask why you don't use a "select" method to check if some data is ready to be read ? As how I see it if you got some GUI to do, your while(1) will kill anything else than network reading.

Comment: Stack overflow gets such a deluge that these type of questions don't seem to get viewed.  This is network sending, not reading, anyway.

Comment: The sending work, it retrasnmist a lot of time, wireshark confirm it. Check the code on the device, you dont debug at the correct place then.

Comment: Is this question not clear enough?  The code is for reference as pertains to socket setup.  My code is only handling tcp indirectly through the linux kernel.

Comment: It's not clear for a point, the two unit are router  on lte ? so you get packet down on device behind it ? or you stream to the router somehow ?

Comment: Updated network info. Two test devices are behind router on lte.  Server doesn't receive sent packets from linux device.  Stream sent to icecast server in some compute farm like linode,digital ocean, etc.

Comment: Does you can ping the device/router when the packet drop from your streaming client ? As LTE network are prompt to network outage.

Comment: Yes, ping works, other ip's udp traffic is passed.

Comment: On the client side does your app still answer ? cna you debug there to be sure everything is ok, as other packet pass.

Comment: Yes.  Routing this traffic through openvpn works too.

Comment: Update the router then, or change it.